# Order lists according to another list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple lists such as :

```
List1=['Canis_lupus','Cattus_catus','Mus_musculus','Rattus_rattus','Bombyx']
List2=['Homo_sapiens','Homo_erectus','Pan_troglodys']
List3=['Cattus_cattus','Bombyx','Homo_erectus','Mus_musculus']
```

And a predefined ordered list with all the element that could be within the **Lists** above=

```
Ordered_list=['Cattus_cattus','Bombyx','Mus_musculus','Homo_sapiens','Pan_troglodys','Canis_lupus','Rattus_rattus','Homo_erectus']
```

So I would like simple to reorder the 3 lists by comparing with the order of elements in `Ordered_list`

The new ordered list should then be :

```
List1=['Cattus_catus','Bombyx','Mus_musculus','Canis_lupus','Rattus_rattus']
List2=['Homo_sapiens','Pan_troglodys','Homo_erectus']
List3=['Cattus_cattus','Bombyx','Mus_musculus','Homo_erectus']
```

Does someone have an idea please ?

Comment: So the information in the ordered list is the same as your three separate list? Why not use it directly and get for example every third index (eg. with `Ordered_list[::3]`) for the third separate list?

Comment: There is a typo in List1. I guess Cattus_catus is supposed to be Cattus_cattus as Cattus_catus (with single t) is not in your Ordered_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess sorting using lambda key function should be able to do the trick.

Please check below

```
list1=['Canis_lupus','Cattus_catus','Mus_musculus','Rattus_rattus','Bombyx']
list2=['Homo_sapiens','Homo_erectus','Pan_troglodys']
list3=['Cattus_cattus','Bombyx','Homo_erectus','Mus_musculus']


Ordered_list=['Cattus_catus','Bombyx','Mus_musculus','Homo_sapiens','Pan_troglodys','Canis_lupus','Rattus_rattus','Homo_erectus']

list1 = sorted(list1, key = lambda val : Ordered_list.index(val))
list2 = sorted(list2, key = lambda val : Ordered_list.index(val))
list3 = sorted(list3, key = lambda val : Ordered_list.index(val))
print(list1)
```

Comment: Pointless lambda, just use the method.

Answer (score 4):

```
List1=['Canis_lupus','Cattus_cattus','Mus_musculus','Rattus_rattus','Bombyx']
List2=['Homo_sapiens','Homo_erectus','Pan_troglodys']
List3=['Cattus_cattus','Bombyx','Homo_erectus','Mus_musculus']

Ordered_list=['Cattus_cattus','Bombyx','Mus_musculus','Homo_sapiens','Pan_troglodys','Canis_lupus','Rattus_rattus','Homo_erectus']

# Create a dictionary with index numbers for ordered list
d = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(Ordered_list)}

# Sort the list in place by the key in the dictionary created above
List1.sort(key=d.get)
print(List1)

>>> ['Cattus_cattus', 'Bombyx', 'Mus_musculus', 'Canis_lupus', 'Rattus_rattus']

# Create a new list instead of modifying in place
a = sorted(List1, key=d.get)

print(a)
print(List1)

>>> ['Cattus_cattus', 'Bombyx', 'Mus_musculus', 'Canis_lupus', 'Rattus_rattus']
>>> ['Canis_lupus', 'Cattus_cattus', 'Mus_musculus', 'Rattus_rattus', 'Bombyx']
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach, create new lists based on your ordered_list.

For this example I fixed the spelling of Cattus_cattus in the first list

```
list1=['Canis_lupus','Cattus_cattus','Mus_musculus','Rattus_rattus','Bombyx']
list2=['Homo_sapiens','Homo_erectus','Pan_troglodys']
list3=['Cattus_cattus','Bombyx','Homo_erectus','Mus_musculus']

ordered_list=[
    'Cattus_cattus','Bombyx','Mus_musculus','Homo_sapiens',
    'Pan_troglodys','Canis_lupus','Rattus_rattus','Homo_erectus'
]
new_list1 = []
new_list2 = []
new_list3 = []

for item in ordered_list:
    if item in list1:
        new_list1.append(item)
    if item in list2:
        new_list2.append(item)
    if item in list3:
        new_list3.append(item)

print(new_list1)
print(new_list2)
print(new_list3)
```